# Enzyme Styledcomponents shallow rendering returning `WithTheme(Component) `

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components, snapshot

This is a simple component I am trying to snapshot test

```
import React from 'react'

// snapshot test for this
export default function DogItem(props) {
    const { imageUrl, name, subBreeds } = props
    return (
        <Card title={name} width={350} m={2}>
            <Img src={imageUrl}></Img>
            <Flex mt={2}>
                {subBreeds.map(breed => (
                    <Badge key={breed.name} primary mr={2}>
                        {breed}
                    </Badge>
                ))}
            </Flex>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

and here is my Jest test case

```
import DogItem from '../DogItem'
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
it('Renders table with correct attributes', () => {
    let rendered = shallow(
        <DogItem imageUrl="testUrl" name="dog name" subBreeds={[1, 2, 3]} />
    )
    console.log(rendered.debug());
})
```

In the output I get this

```
  <Img src="testUrl" />
  <Flex mt={2}>
    <WithTheme(Component) primary={true} mr={2}>
      1
    </WithTheme(Component)>
    <WithTheme(Component) primary={true} mr={2}>
      2
    </WithTheme(Component)>
    <WithTheme(Component) primary={true} mr={2}>
      3
    </WithTheme(Component)>
  </Flex>
</WithTheme(Component)>
```

I am not quite sure why I am getting `WithTheme(Component)` instead of `Badge` or `Img`. I do realize these components are styled components however shallow is just suppose to render the one level deep right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your tree is rendered one level deep, that's still correct.

Second, it's about way `enzyme` realizes what component to output for human-readable form like `.debug()`(and also for `enzyme-to-json` as well). It just uses `displayName` property, and for HOCs like `withTheme` you have to specify it manually:

```
const Badge = withTheme(...)
Badge.displayName = 'Badge';
```

In their repo team's member mentions [their Babel plugin](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging) that(probably) will do that for you automatically. But telling the truth I did not get what it can use for `displayName` alongside just file name. Give it a try anyway.

Without that there is no way for `withTheme` to know what *variable's name* you are going to use.

Comment: This was the issue. I was using a third party library which didn't have displayName